# Export function

Tags: powershell, powershell-2.0, powershell-3.0

I am trying to create a function in which a user has to give a filename that can not containt an empty string. Besides that, the string can not contain a dot. When I run this function, I keep looping when I enter "test" for example. Any idea as to why?

```
 function Export-Output {
     do {
         $exportInvoke = Read-Host "Do you want to export this output to a new .txt file? [Y/N]"
     } until ($exportInvoke -eq "Y" -or "N")

     if ($exportInvoke -eq "Y") {
        do {
           $script:newLog = Read-Host "Please enter a filename! (Exclude the extension)"
           if ($script:newLog.Length -lt 1 -or $script:newLog -match ".*") {
               Write-Host "Wrong input!" -for red
           }
       } while ($script:newLog.Length -lt 1 -or $script:newLog -match ".*")

       ni "$script:workingDirectory\$script:newLog.txt" -Type file -Value $exportValue | Out-Null
    }
}
```

EDIT:

On a related note:

```
do {
    $exportInvoke = Read-Host "Do you want to export this output to a new .txt file? [Y/N]"
} until ($exportInvoke -eq "Y" -or "N")
```

When I use these lines of code I can simply hit enter to circumvent the `Read-Host`. When I replace `"Y" -or "N"` with simply `"Y"` it does not. Any idea as to why this is happening?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `-match` operator checks against a regular expression, so this:

```
$script:newLog -match ".*"
```

is testing if the filename contains any charachter except newline (`.`) 0 or more times (`*`). This condition will always be true, thus creating an infinite loop.

If you want to test for a literal dot, you must escape it:

```
$script:newLog -match '\.'
```

---

As for your other question, you're misunderstanding how logical and comparison operators work. `$exportInvoke -eq "Y" -or "N"` does not mean `$exportInvoke -eq ("Y" -or "N")`, i.e. variable equals either "Y" or "N". It means `($exportInvoke -eq "Y") -or ("N")`. Since the expression `"N"` does not [evaluate to zero](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/powershell/archive/2006/12/24/boolean-values-and-operators.aspx), PowerShell interprets it as `$true`, so your condition becomes `($exportInvoke -eq "Y") -or $true`, which is always true. You need to change the condition to this:

```
$exportInvoke -eq "Y" -or $exportInvoke -eq "N"
```

Comment: Alright that helps alot. I edited the main post for another small related question. Would you mind taking a look at that ?

Comment: Much appreciated. I bookmarked the link. In for a good read I guess...
To be honest I am not completely sure yet why "N" becomes $true but I guess I'll find out.

Answer (score 1):

Use this to test your input:

`!($script:newLog.contains('.')) -and !([String]::IsNullOrEmpty($script:newLog)) -and !([String]::IsNullOrWhiteSpace($script:newLog))`

Your regular expression (`-match ".*"` is essentially matching on everything.